# Code is not working in IE8 but working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Here is my code:**

```
    var allSsnTinControls = $("td[controlnamespace='EbixExchange.Web.UI.SocialSecurityNumberControl']").children("span[controlnamespace='EbixExchange.Web.UI.SocialSecurityNumberControl']");

    var officerSSN = $(allSsnTinControls).filter(function () { return $(this).is('[readonly="true"]'); });

    allSsnTinControls = officerSSN;

    if (allSsnTinControls.length > 0)
```

in IE9 length is coming greater than 0  but in IE8 it's undefined

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: Wait, why are we testing jQuery for IE8 in 2015?  How do you even GET access to IE8?  I'll have to install Windows XP...

Comment: thanks for your response.